# How to format collection_path with extension using Her gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

In order to get JSON from an API I am making requests to, I need to add the `.json` extension to my request. For example:

```
/test/api/people/2323 # returns XML
/test/api/people/2323.json # returns JSON
```

The requesting app uses Rails with the Her gem. According to the [Her README](https://github.com/remiprev/her#notes-about-paths), you can specify a collection path like this.

```
collection_path "organizations/:organization_id/users"
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to add an extension with that format. It does not work with either:

```
collection_path "test/api/people/:id.json"
```

or

```
collection_path "test/api/people.json"
```

Here is what my initializer for `Her` looks like:

```
LOCAL = Her::API.new
LOCAL.setup url: "https://example.com", headers: { "Content-Type" => "application/json" } do |config|
  config.use Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded
  config.use Her::Middleware::DefaultParseJSON
  config.use Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp
end
```

Is there a step I'm missing with the setup of Her/Faraday or is there some way to request JSON without specifying an extension? The API I want to access is also written in Rails.

Comment: Can you be more precise about the url that you want to make a json request to? I am not sure if you want `https://example.com/test/api/people/2323` or `https://example.comfind_a_doctor/api/providers/:id`. Either way, you shouldn't need to add the extension name in your collection_path. And I suspect the problem is that Her expects RESTful routes, and you seem to not have them if your url includes `people/:id` in the route instead of `users/:id` or `persons/:id`.

Comment: @BryanDimas I updated the examples to be consistent. If I don't need to add the extension to my collection_path, how do I tell the API that I want JSON? `test/api/people` is consistent across all requests for the `people` resource, doesn't that make it RESTful? When I leave `.json` off the collection path, Her does find the right page, but I haven't found an adapter to parse XML correctly.

Comment: I think adding the middleware `Her::Middleware::AcceptJSON` should make a json request for you automatically without specifying `.json` at the end of your url. It just adds the header `Accept: application/json`. You might also want to show the error you're getting if the above still does not work.

Comment: @BryanDimas That seemed to do the trick, thanks! If you want to post your comment as an answer I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help. Posted as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there some way to make a JSON request without specifying an extension?

Yes, you need to add the middleware `Her::Middleware::AcceptJSON`. All it does is add the `"Accept: application/json"` HTTP header.

Extremely simple :), here are [the docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/remiprev/her/Her/Middleware/AcceptJSON) and the [source code](https://github.com/remiprev/her/blob/master/lib/her/middleware/accept_json.rb), only 17 lines of code.

So now your file `config/initializers/her.rb` looks something like this:

```
Her::API.setup url: "https://example.com" do |config|
  config.use Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded
  config.use Her::Middleware::DefaultParseJSON
  config.use Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp
  # middleware to make a json request by default
  config.use Her::Middleware::AcceptJSON
end
```